# gmaps4rails - remove markers and display map without them

Tags: reload, gmaps4rails, markers

I have list of people when every person has his boss. So beside map is list of bosses in form of checkboxes. If I click on boss checkbox, people of boss are displayed on map as markers.

I need when boss has no people display map centered on some place, but there is some problem with javascript.

Controller

```
if params[:boss]
  bosses_array = params[:boss].map(&:to_i)

  @bosses = User.joins(:roles).where("roles.name ='boss' and users.id in (?)", bosses_array)
  people = People.where("boss_id in (?)", bosses_array)

  if people.count != 0
    @json = people.to_gmaps4rails
    @markers = true
  else
    @markers = false
  end

else  
  @bosses = User.joins(:roles).where("roles.name ='boss'")
  @markers = false
end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json}) %>

<% content_for :scripts do -%>
<script type="text/javascript">

if(<%= @markers %>)
{
 Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
 Gmaps.load_map = function() {
 Gmaps.map.map_options.maxZoom = 15;
 Gmaps.map.initialize();

 Gmaps.map.markers =  <%= raw @json %>;
 Gmaps.map.create_markers();
 Gmaps.map.callback();
 Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_zoom = true;      
 Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
 };

 Gmaps.loadMaps();

}
else
{

 Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
 Gmaps.load_map = function() {
 Gmaps.map.map_options.maxZoom = 15;
 Gmaps.map.map_options.center_latitude = "30";
 Gmaps.map.map_options.center_longitude = "20";
 Gmaps.map.initialize();
 //create markers without data, so there are no markers
 Gmaps.map.create_markers();
 Gmaps.map.callback();
 Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_zoom = true;      
 Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
 };

 Gmaps.loadMaps();


}


</script>
```

If bosses have some people markers are displayed, but when there are no people old markers stays without deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i faced before.

To remove the markers, we need to pass empty markers list, else it would retain the previous markers list and display them.

```
Gmaps.map.initialize();
//create markers without data, so there are no markers
Gmaps.map.markers = []
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
```

Other way is, you can replace the markers with jquery

```
Gmaps.loadMaps();
Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers('');
```

Hope this would help you.

Thanks.